# CiviMail Next and Test Buttons Disabled

Tags: civimail

I'm trying to set up a mailing in Civi using a smart group.  I have the Mailing Name, Recipients, Subject, Content, and the two unsubscribe tokens.  The test and next buttons are still disabled.  I'm using Civi 4.6.4 in WordPress.
The autoresponder is currently disabled.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have required tokens in the plaintext version as well?

Comment: I didn't at first but I filled it in and the buttons are still disabled.

Comment: There are a couple of questions that have a similar issue - http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/3785/610 suggests enabling the autoresponder might help.

Comment: I've tried enabling the auto-responder already.

Comment: You mention the unsubscribe tokens - you also need the domain address (you may already have this, but just in case). It's also probably worth updating to the latest version. The q/a here: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6558/send-test-and-next-not-clickable-greyed-due-to-missing-value-in-reply-id-field/6559 suggests there might be a missing value in the db, so if updating doesn't help, maybe follow that up?

Comment: I posted a suggested cause and a solution in the links listed above but will repeat here for ease of finding it: in this case, the Auto-responder (from Administer > CiviMail > Headers, Footers, and Automatic Messages) was disabled when the first mailing was created (actually, all of the pre-configured messages/headers/footers were disabled). Enabling all of them and setting as default didn't fix the already created mailing (the "Send Test" and "Next" buttons were still disabled) but everything worked properly in a new mailing, created after enabling pre-configured messages/headers/footers.